# How does 非机动车 (fēijīdòngchē) mean "bicycle"?

Tags: meaning, usage, word

In the road sign below, we have the following:

> 非机动车靠右行驶
>
> fēijīdòngchē kàoyòu xíngshǐ

[image: 非机动车靠右行驶]

Which breaks apart as:

- [非机动车](http://dict.cn/%E9%9D%9E%E6%9C%BA%E5%8A%A8%E8%BD%A6) = bicycle (with [机动](http://dict.cn/%E6%9C%BA%E5%8A%A8) meaning "mobile")
- [靠右](http://dict.cn/%E9%9D%A0%E5%8F%B3) = keep right
- [行驶](http://dict.cn/%E8%A1%8C%E9%A9%B6) = travel along a route

However, I'm not clear on how 非机动车 means bicycle.  Ordinarily, I would expect "bicycle" to be [自行车](http://dict.cn/%E8%87%AA%E8%A1%8C%E8%BD%A6) (zìxíngchē), and I'm unfamiliar with this as an alternative.

**Question**: How does 非机动车 (fēijīdòngchē) mean "bicycle"?

Comment: Bicycle can also be 单车, and is more a colloquial term..you may hear people say 踏单车　　It may be more common in Hong Kong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't only means bicycle.

"非机动车" is non-motorized vehicle, NMV, including tractors,human cargo vehicles, animal-drawn vehicles, etc., according to [*the explaination of "非机动车" in Baidu Baike*](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=KhzWSE65zC4MFwuMz2FNTx0vpNz-voCq2lYiALKbgt2rjrTPKx8cbcycm1fmW0xvEmfNZ2lkGUFeVDVkPDvyJrSKyS8HJNMD-4en9kOYHFNg25Yllnf4nB5aIwR-u_Bi).

So bicycle is only one sort of NMVs and is used to reprensent NMV on the sign because it's very common.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't mean bicycle.
the word 机动 means motorized or power-driven, the reason why you see a picture of bicycle in the sign is that bicycle is a very popular 非机动车